# Sum 2 Table values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to sum two values across two tables.  I have a pending amount calculated for both tables, and now need to see the sum of both calculated fields in a multi-row card. Table 1 gives me a dollar amount, table 2 gives me a dollar amount.  I need the sum of the two amounts.

Table 1 calculated field:

```
Pending Tender (FTL-CS) = IF('ICS Que'[DeliveryDate]=BLANK(),BLANK(),'ICS Que'[TenderedAmount])
```

Table 2 Calculated field:

```
Pending Tender (FTL-AP) = IF('AP Que'[DeliveryDate]=BLANK(),BLANK(),'AP Que'[TenderedAmount])
```

Sum of both field attempt:

```
Pending Tender (FTL) = CALCULATE(SUM('AP Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-AP)]&SUM('ICS Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-CS)])))
```

I know it is in my syntax but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is the following:

```
    Pending Tender (FTL) := 
CALCULATE(SUM('AP Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-AP)]&SUM('ICS Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-CS)])))
```

It should be written as the below, where the first `SUM` has a closing bracket, and there is a `+` instead of using `&` between the two `SUM`

```
Pending Tender (FTL):=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'AP Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-AP)] )
        + SUM ( 'ICS Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-CS)] )
)
```

Or it could be rewritten as the below, since the calculate is redundant unless you are having a filter condition on it.

```
Pending Tender (FTL):=
SUM ( 'AP Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-AP)] )
    + SUM ( 'ICS Que'[Pending Tender (FTL-CS)] )
```

Finally as a recommendation, I would personally avoid using ( or ) in measure names, since they can be mistaken for opening and closing brackets.